# Can't run Kubernetes dashboard after installing Kubernetes cluster on rancher/server

Tags: kubernetes, rancher

- Docker: 1.12.6
- rancher/server: 1.5.10
- rancher/agent: 1.2.2

Tried two ways to install Kubernetes cluster on rancher/server.

## Method 1: Use Kubernetes environment

### Infrastructure/Hosts

Agent hosts disconnected sometimes.

[image]

### Stacks

All green except `kubernetes-ingress-lbs`. It has 0 containers.

[image]

## Method 2: Use Default environment

### Infrastructure/Hosts

Set some labels to rancher server and agent hosts.

[image]

### Stacks

All green except `kubernetes-ingress-lbs`. It has 0 containers.

[image]

---

Both of them have this issue: `kubernetes-ingress-lbs` 0 services 0 containers. Then can't access Kubernetes dashboard.

[image]

Why didn't been installed by rancher?
And, is it necessary to add those labels for Kubernetes cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you enable to "Show System" containers in the UI, you should be able to see the dashboard container running under Namespace: kube-system. If this container is not running then the dashboard will not be able to load.

Answer (score 2):

Here is RIGHT Kubernetes Cluster deployed on Rancher server:

[image: kubernete-cluster]

Turning on the `Show System`, you can find the service of `kubernetes-dashboard` under the namespace of `kube-system`.

Well, by using the version of kubernetes is `v1.5.4`, you should prepare in advance to pull the below `Docker Images`:

[image]

By reading [rancher/catalog](https://github.com/rancher/rancher-catalog/tree/v1.6-development/infra-templates/k8s) and [rancher/kuberetes-package](https://github.com/rancher/kubernetes-package/tree/master/addon-templates/kubectl), you can know and even modify the **config files(like docker-compose.yml, rancher-compose.yml and so on)** by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You might have to enable kubernetes add-on service within rancher environment template.

manage environments >> edit kubernetes default template >> enable add-on service and save the new template with the preferred name.

Now launch the cluster using customized templates.